# How to check if a string contains characters passed in RegExp?

Tags: regex, dart

```dart
void main() {
  var regExp = RegExp('=:');
  var s1 = 'string'; 
  var s2 = 'string:';
  var s3 = 'string:=';
  
  print(regExp.hasMatch(s1)); // Should print false
  print(regExp.hasMatch(s2)); // Should print true
  print(regExp.hasMatch(s3)); // Should print true
}
```

I want to check if my string contains any of the characters I used in `RegExp`. I'm very new to `RegExp` and I believe there's something very trivial which I am not aware of. I can do it using plain Dart but I'm looking for a way through `RegExp`.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `'[=:]'` instead of `'=:'`,  the square brackets mean "match ANY of these characters".